# Why $\|f\|_p=u_f(0)^\frac{1}{p}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Suppose that $f \in H^p$, where $0<p<\infty$. Let $u_f$ be the least harmonic majorant of $|f|^p$. Why is it true that
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_p=u_f(0)^\frac{1}{p}?
\end{equation} I was hinted to start with the harmonic functions in $D(0;R)$ with boundary values $|f|^p$ for $R<1$ and then let $R \to 1$. However, I don't know how to use this hint. Please help.

Comment: How do you know there _is_ a least harmonic majorant? The construction of $u_f$ is useful here

Comment: Explicitly, $u_f$ is given by $$u_f(z)=\int_T P_z(\zeta) |f(\zeta)|^p dm(\zeta).$$ Am I right?